# Java : Making a method to sort an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to make a method for sorting arrays
I also have my array made, but I'm not sure about returning it and calling it. Any help please?

```
public void bubbleSort(String words [][] ) {

        for (byte count1 = 0; count1 < words.length - 1; count1++) 
            for (byte count2 = 0; count2 < ((words.length)-count1); count2++) {
            System.out.print(words[count1][count2] + " ");

            Arrays.sort(words); 

        }
        return words [count1][count2];
    }
```

Comment: Why would you want to return anything? Sorting an array changes the contents; there usually isn't a return value (except perhaps a `boolean` indicating whether any changes actually took place). In any event, since your method is declared `void`, you can't return a value.

Comment: thats a rather strange piece of code. what exactly do you want to achieve? apart from that: methods with return-type `void` don't return anything. just leave the `return` statement away

Comment: If you're manipulating the array (`words`) that's passed in, you don't need to return it - you've declared your method to have return type `void`, so just get rid of your return statement. Having said that, you're invoking `Arrays.sort()` on the entire array for _every element_... you may want to check your logic there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to return the array to the main() functions as change in the contents of the array reflects in the array passed during function call in main. In the main function do the following :

1. Intialize a 2-d String like :

   ```
   String[][] rows = new String[10][10];
   ```
2. Put your  required array in it.
3. Then call the function as

   ```
   bubbleSort(rows);
   ```

The rows array contains your sorted string.